# How can I delay, or pause, a function in ansca's corona? (lua)

Tags: iphone, windows, sdk, lua, coronasdk

I can't find it documented anywhere :/

(question is the title)

found [this](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/timerperformwithdelay) but can't get it to work.

```
function onCollision( event )
   --code-- 
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", listener )

 local function listener( event )
     timer.performWithDelay(
1000, onCollision )
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is one of code order.  `function` essentially sets the value for the given symbol.  [From the Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html):

> The statement
>
> ```
>  function f () body end
> ```
>
> translates to
>
> ```
>  f = function () body end
> ```

As such, `listener` is `nil` at the time you're passing it to `addEventListener`.  Reorder, and it should work:

```
function onCollision( event )
   --code-- 
end

local function listener( event )
  timer.performWithDelay(1000, onCollision )
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", listener )
```